# Find the population from a model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{2p(7-p)}{700}$$

Given $p(0) = 3$ and $p \gt 0$, find $p(57)$.

I'm able to separate the variables and get

$$\frac{700}{(2p)(7-p)} = dt$$

I then separate to different bases.

$$\frac{700}{(2p)(7-p)} = \frac{A}{p} + \frac{B}{7-p}$$

I never understood this part in Calc 2 and it still eludes me on how to solve at this point.

Comment: Your separation of the variables is not correct. You should have $700(7-p)$ in the numerator and $2p$ in the denominator.

Comment: I edited my answer after your edit.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following: 
$$\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{2p}{700(7-p)}\Rightarrow \frac{700(7-p)}{2p}dp=dt \\ \Rightarrow 350\left (\frac{7}{p}-1\right )dp=dt \\ \Rightarrow \int 350\left (\frac{7}{p}-1\right )dp=\int dt \\ \Rightarrow 350\left (7 \ln p-p\right )=t+c$$

Using the condition $p(0)=3$ find the value of $c$ and then calculate the value of $p(57)$.

$$$$

**EDIT:**

After your edit we have the following:

$$\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{2p(7-p)}{700} \Rightarrow \frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{p(7-p)}{350} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{p(7-p)}dp=\frac{1}{350}dt\Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{p(7-p)}dp=\int \frac{1}{350}dt$$

To calculate the intergral $$\int \frac{1}{p(7-p)}dp$$ we write the expression $\frac{1}{p(7-p)}$ in the form $\frac{A}{p}+\frac{B}{7-p}$.

$$\frac{1}{p(7-p)}=\frac{A}{p}+\frac{B}{7-p}=\frac{A(7-p)+Bp}{p(7-p)}=\frac{7A+(B-A)p}{p(7-p)} \\ \Rightarrow 7A=1 \text{ and } B-A=0 \\ \Rightarrow A=\frac{1}{7} \text{ and } B=A=\frac{1}{7}$$

So the integral is equal to $$\int \frac{1}{p(7-p)}dp=\frac{1}{7}\int \left (\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{7-p}\right )dt=\frac{1}{7}(\ln p-\ln |7-p|)+C$$

Therefore, $$\int \frac{1}{p(7-p)}dp=\int \frac{1}{350}dt \Rightarrow \frac{1}{7}(\ln p-\ln |7-p|)=\frac{t}{350}+c \\ \Rightarrow \frac{1}{7}\ln \left ( \frac{p}{|7-p|}\right )=\frac{t}{350}+c$$

For $t=0$ we have $p=3$, so $$c=\frac{1}{7}\ln \left (\frac{3}{4}\right )$$

So, we have $$\frac{1}{7}\ln \left ( \frac{p}{|7-p|}\right )=\frac{t}{350}+\frac{1}{7}\ln \left (\frac{3}{4}\right ) \Rightarrow \ln \left ( \frac{p}{|7-p|}\right )=\frac{t}{50}+\ln \left (\frac{3}{4}\right ) \Rightarrow \frac{p}{|7-p|}=\frac{3}{4}e^{\frac{t}{50}} \Rightarrow p=|7-p|\frac{3}{4}e^{\frac{t}{50}}$$

Solve for $p$ and then find its value for $t=57$.